# Parsing bytes sent via netcat

Tags: c++, bash, sockets, netcat

I'm running a server using sockets in C++. Once I've connected to the client(using netcat for this), I have a function that reads what the client has sent and tries to parse it.

**The structure**:

```
struct m
{
           uint8_t m1;
}

struct str
{
           uint64_t a;    
           uint32_t b;
           uint32_t c;
}
```

**The function**:

```
 int f(int x){
 char s[1024];
 if (read(x,s,sizeof(s)-1) > 0){
      m *msg = reinterpret_cast<m *>(s);
      if(msg->m1 == 0)
          {
           str *st = reinterpret_cast<str *>(s+1);
           uint64_t a = htonll(st->u);     
           uint32_t b = htonl(st->v);
           uint32_t c = htonl(st->w);
           std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<std::endl;
          }
  else
  {....
  }
}
```

**Edit**:

```
uint64_t htonll(uint64_t value)
{
// The answer is 42
static const int num = 42;

// Check the endianness
if (*reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&num) == num)
{
    const uint32_t high_part = htonl(static_cast<uint32_t>(value >> 32));
    const uint32_t low_part = htonl(static_cast<uint32_t>(value & 0xFFFFFFFFLL));

    return (static_cast<uint64_t>(low_part) << 32) | high_part;
} else
{
    return value;
}
}
```

For this particular case, there should be no issue with padding. I'm able to correctly parse and reach within the `*msghead == '0'` if condition. However, I'm not getting the values I expect from `a, b and c`. I've tried a lot of cases, but the values don't make much sense.

How I'm testing:

```
echo -n -e '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01' | nc localhost 9000
```

Ideally I should get the output as 1 1 1, but I get 0 0 0.
Also, if I change this to

```
echo -n -e '\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01' | nc localhost 9000
```

I get `1 0 0`

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the byte order that I can fix, but in either case, there seems to be some other issue as well.

Comment: Is the [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) equal on both sides of the connection?

Comment: Also note that `0` is not equal to `'0'` using any encoding currently existing.

Comment: Lastly, what do you think the `s` in `htons` stands for? Answer: It stands for ***short***, i.e. a 16-bit integer. There is no standard conversion function for 64 bit types, but there is for 32 bit integers.

Comment: I'm using localhost, so endianness is equal. That comparison works out, the major problem is why I'm getting such absurd outputs for the last print statement.

Comment: Then you're not sending what you claim to be sending. Which IMO makes the whole question almost as worthless as the code (which is missing variable declarations, like `buf` or `msghead`, and what is the type `str`?). Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And of course, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made some edits that make it clearer. I'm also using ntohl now for the 32 bit integers. I've also realised that the pattern is an error between the order of two bytes. Ideally b should be reading \x00\x00\x00\x01 but it prints 256 (which would be by swapping the two pairs adjacently). Similarly for c, \x00\x00\x01\x00 gives me 1.

Comment: The problem seems to be that only half of the bits are being picked up in a, b and c via reinterpret cast. I'm not sure why that's the case.

Comment: Besides your invalid use of the `htons` function (unless you overloaded it?), can you please check `sizeof(str)`? Is it what you expect it to be? There's no padding between the members?

Comment: Yes. It is exactly 16 as expected. The program is just picking half of the bytes it should for b and c.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
uint64_t a = htons(st->u);     
uint32_t b = htons(st->v);
uint32_t c = htons(st->w);
```

If you read [this POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html) you will see that `htons` is for ***16-bit*** integers, and `htonl` is for 32-bit integers. There are no existing *standard* functions for 64-bit types.

However, on Linux using the GNU C library there are the [`bswap_x`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bswap.3.html) set of functions which have a 64-bit variant.

Comment: I've made modifications for this. I'm using a function I found on stackoverflow itself for the 64 bit variant as well as htonl for the 32 bit ints. I'm still facing problems. Only the last two bytes are being considered and those are swapped too (input that I've mentioned above, being sent by netcat).

Comment: \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01 gives me 256 for a, and if I make any changes to the first 6 bytes, like \x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x01, it still stays the same.

Comment: @rsaw27 Well your `htonll` function [works](https://ideone.com/1pbADr). So the problem might be that you maybe don't receive all data? You only check that `read` returns a value larger than `0`, but you don't actually *know* how much it read. With TCP You might need multiple calls to receive all data. And have tried printing the raw data you actually receive? Is it what you expect?